# eMail verification in android to get genuine users

Tags: android

In my Android application sign Up page taking email id. We want to know whether it is valid / not. I have gone through this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-1/

But i want email verification methods to get genuine users. Just like all other applications.
Thanks

Comment: user give their email to your server, your server send activation email to that new email. done.

Comment: Is there any tutorial to know more.